# finding the minimal cover of a given set of functional dependencies

Tags: functional-dependencies

I have a set of functional dependencies for a relational schema and need to find the minimal cover. I understand the basic concepts of eliminating redundant lines but am struggling to get it done. What is the most efficient way to complete this?

These are the functional dependencies:

```
client      --> office

stock       --> exchange, dividend

broker      --> profile

company     --> stock

client      --> risk_profile, analyst 

analyst     --> broker

stock, broker   --> investment, volume

stock       --> company

investment  --> commission, return

stock, broker   --> client

account     --> assets
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert all the FDs such that the RHS of any FD consist of only single attribute

```
client      --> office
stock       --> exchange
stock       --> dividend
broker      --> profile
company     --> stock
client      --> risk_profile
client      -->analyst
analyst     --> broker
stock, broker   --> investment
stock, broker   --> volume
stock       --> company
investment  --> return
investment  --> commission
stock, broker   --> client
account     --> assets
```

Next step is  we need to look for
redundant attributes on the LHS

Pick FD that have 2 or more than 2 attributes on  LHS

```
1.stock, broker   --> investment
```

Remove one attribute at a time form LHS and compute the clouser of the remaining attributes if the clouser of attributes include the eliminated attribute then you can actually remove the attribute.

Remove stock form 1 and compute clouser for broker

```
(broker)+ = {broker,profile,investment,return ,commission}
```

which does not contain stock so you cannot remove stock

Remove broker form 1 and compute clouser for stock

```
(stock)+ = {stock,exchange,dividend,investment,return,commission,company}
```

which does not contain broker so you cannot remove broker

you can play the same game for following FDs

```
2.stock, broker   --> volume
3.stock, broker   --> client
```

For FD 3. you will find that broker can be removed leading to following FDs

```
client      --> office
stock       --> exchange
stock       --> dividend
broker      --> profile
company     --> stock
client      --> risk_profile
client      -->analyst
analyst     --> broker
stock, broker   --> investment
stock, broker   --> volume
stock       --> company
investment  --> return
investment  --> commission
stock       --> client
account     --> assets
```

final step is to  look for FDs that are redundant.
To check a FD of the form X ---> Y is redundant compute clouser of X and check if it contains Y,If such is the case then you can safely remove the FD from minimal cover set.This is illustrated below.

```
 client      --> office
```

compute clouser of client

```
(client)+ = { client , risk_proflie,analyst,broker,profile }
```

the clouser does not contain office so you cannot remove it.
repeat the final step and you will find that no FD can be removed,Hence minimal cover set is

```
client      --> office
stock       --> exchange
stock       --> dividend
broker      --> profile
company     --> stock
client      --> risk_profile
client      -->analyst
analyst     --> broker
stock, broker   --> investment
stock, broker   --> volume
stock       --> company
investment  --> return
investment  --> commission
stock       --> client
account     --> assets
```